# JQuery Show/Hide causes page re-size errors

Tags: jquery, show-hide

Let me first describe what I'm trying to accomplish then explain the bug/error/problem.
I am trying to accomplish putting 3 pages on one page. My boss has decided that he wanted a presentation for a webpages to have a slide effect and show essentially 3 pages on one page. The reason for this was to have no more loading and when the user presses the right button or swipes left on a tablet they will go to the next page.

To accomplish this task I am using the hide/show event with 3 divs. So basically when the page loads Div 1 will be displayed and div 2 & 3 are hidden. When the button is pressed div 2 is shown and div 1& 3 are hidden, so on and so on. This works just fine. The problem arises when the page is re-sized after the page has loaded and div 2 or 3 is hidden. Div 2 and 3 have images on them. If you re-size the page while looking at div 1, div 2 doesn't show up until you re-size the page (Slightly or a lot doesn't matter).

Here is an example of what I'm talking about. Try loading the page then re-sizing it then pressing the Brands button in the lower left. Nothing will show up till you re-size the window again. The show and hides are in the on-click even handler. Any ideas why this may be happening or how to fix it in the current configuration.

Link Removed, since problem has been answered

Comment: That's because show() and hide() sets the display property, which in turn removes the elements from the documents flow. To avoid that set the opacity or the visibility property instead.

Comment: Problem with that is then i ll have giant white spaces on the page because of the hidden property. Any ways around this?

Comment: Well, either you hide the elements and remove them from the flow, causing other elements that are in the flow to move etc, or you hide the elements without removing them from the document flow, causing a blank space where the elements should be. This is the nature of CSS, what else are you expecting?

Comment: I dont know. Removed from the flow to allow page to move and change and events taken to them to still be handled on them